# How to create sitemap on our website for SEO ranking

Tags: sitemap, sitemap.xml

I have create a sitemap XML file for my website from online sitemap creator tool(website). Then after I put this  sitemap.xml file to my server root directory.
Then I  went  Google webmaster  (https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/dashboard) and  add my website domain to on Google webmaster and verify my domain by clicking verify button on Google webmaster and I also added sitemap.xml file on Google webmaster on my account

These step I performed for sitemap of my website. But still I am not getting any sitemap for my website.
Please advice me where I am wrong.OR How can I create sitemap for my website.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by your are still not getting any sitemap for your website? Can you clarify? It seems you have performed the right steps so far.

Answer (score 0):

Create sitemap.xml here: 
https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/

Download from page sitemap.xml file (save on desktop)

Upload to your server (filezilla program or ssh) main folder domain.com/sitemap.xml

And add in google webmaster tools panel that all
[image]

Answer (score -1):

these sitemap which you created is used by **search engines** like google, yahoo, microsoft for crawling of website
if you want **website map**(**which you or your website user can see**) then you have to create seperate page for it like other webpages